# Belong to spec failing in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have a model called Option.

```rb
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :scheme
  validate :check_for_quantity

  def check_for_quantity
    if self.quantity > self.scheme.remaining_options
      errors.add(:quantity, "cannot be more than the remaining options #{ self.scheme.remaining_options.to_i}")
    end
  end
end
```

and a model called Scheme.

```rb
class Scheme < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :share_class
  belongs_to :equity_pool
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy

  attr_accessor :percentage

  def ownership
    self.remaining_options * 100 / self.company.total_fdsc
  end

  def remaining_options
    self.initial_size - self.options.sum(&:quantity)
  end
end
```

My spec for Option Model looks like this

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Option, type: :model do

  describe "Associations" do
    subject { create (:option) }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:scheme) } 
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:vesting_schedule).optional }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user) }
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:company) }
  end
end
```

When I run this spec the first example gives an error

1) Option Associations is expected to belong to scheme required: true

```
 Failure/Error: if self.quantity > self.scheme.remaining_options

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `remaining_options' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/option.rb:9:in `check_for_quantity'
```

What is the problem here?

My options factory bot

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :option do
    security "MyString"
    board_status false
    board_approval_date "2018-08-16"
    grant_date "2018-08-16"
    expiration_date "2018-08-16"
    quantity 1
    exercise_price 1.5
    vesting_start_date "2018-08-16"
    vesting_schedule nil
    scheme
    user
    company
  end
end
```

Comment: You use FactoryBot, I suppose? Did you add scheme association to the Option factory? The error means that test subject has no scheme

Comment: Yes i did add the scheme association

Comment: I tried it, still the same error

Comment: I just started learning rspec and testing and I was trying to test my framework. Then this happened. I know it doesn't matter but now that I have discovered an issue I can't just leave it there right?

Comment: The reason this test is failing has to mean something and there should be a solution for it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a condition to the validation so that it is not fired if the association is nil.

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :scheme
  validate :check_for_quantity, unless: -> { self.scheme.nil? }

  def check_for_quantity
    if self.quantity > self.scheme.remaining_options
      errors.add(:quantity, "cannot be more than the remaining options #{ self.scheme.remaining_options.to_i}")
    end
  end
end
```

You may also want to ensure that `self.quantity` is a number and not nil to avoid `NoMethodError: undefined method > for nil:NilClass` which you can do with a numericality validation.

```
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :scheme
  validates_numericality_of :quantity
  validate :check_for_quantity, if: -> { self.scheme && self.quantity }

  def check_for_quantity
    if self.quantity > self.scheme.remaining_options
      errors.add(:quantity, "cannot be more than the remaining options #{ self.scheme.remaining_options.to_i}")
    end
  end
end
```